# Issues with appending array to anonymous array - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, .net-core, anonymous-types

I'm trying to append array to anonymous array and I received this error:

```
No best type found for implicitly typed-array.
```

Here is the array I want to append:

```
var products = myProductList.Select(x => new
{
    isAvailable = 0,
    photo = x?.ImageUrl
}).ToArray();
```

Here is the part of the code where I'm trying to append it (my products array) to, so I want to append rest of the array data to `productImages` anonymous array:

```
var articles_data = new
            {
                products = new[]
                {
                        new
                        {
                            prodDate = product.GetDate();
                            prodtOrdNumb = product.OrdinalNumber,
                            productAmount = product.Amount
                            }),
                            productImages = new[] {
                                new 
                                {
                                    isAvailable = 1,
                                    photo = productFile?.ImageUrl
                                }, 
                                products.ToArray() // HERE I TRIED TO APPEND MY ARRAY
                            }
                        }
                    }
            };
```

As you can see guys I have posted where I've tried to append my array and I've received:

> No best type found for implicitly typed-array.

Any kind of help would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: Use a list instead of an array.  If you use array you need to use the concat method to combine two arrays.

Comment: @jdweng why is that? Could you provide me an example please. Thanks a lot

Comment: `productImages = new[] { new { isAvailable = 1, ... } }.Concat(products).ToArray()`

Comment: @madreflection Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Roxy'Pro because arrays are stored in a fixed contiguous block of memory and then you need to recreate it for example using concat to extend the array.